# My external hard drive not detected from my Windows pc despite can be detected from my Samsung tablet

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, external-hard-drive, usb-storage

I have an external hard drive Seagate model: SRD0NF1 size 1TB and it is not being detected on my Windows PC.

The PC specs:

```
Windows 10 Home
64bit
ASUS rog GL752VW
```

When I say its not detected, it means that it is not showing on "This PC".

I also keep getting this error:

[image]

When I press the error, this window shows up:

[image]

On device manager, I got port reset fail:

[image]

On diskmanagement, there is only my internal HDD:

[image]

Here are the things that I've tried to resolve the problem:

1. Switch usb port, both usb2 and 3 dont work
2. On/off my pc
3. Update Windows
4. Uninstall device on Device manager, then restart my PC.
5. Since I can use this hard disk on my tablet, it means the cable and hard disk itself is ok.
6. Update driver on Device manager (my pc is up to date as of this afternoo.
7. Go to PC repair shop. He said couldn't do it, but refuse to specify why.

Can anyone suggest a solution? What do this error mean and how do I go about resolving it?

I actually tried some more stuff:

- Run diagnostic.
- Disable USB selective suspend.

Answer (score 0):

As the disk is not showing in Disk Management, then there is not much
that you can do.

You could try to reformat it on the tablet, but if this doesn't help
to make it show up in Disk Management then this is hopeless.

Comment: Actually the disk show and then not show on disk management. Sometimes when i plug in, it shows, then stop showing. What do u think the root cause?

Comment: I have had disks like that. This means that it has gone bad. Even if you manage to format it while it's showing, you can't trust it not to disappear again with your data.